# Converting lists to lowercase in python and comparing them

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a spell checker which will read in a dictionary (`words.txt`) and then read in a text file (`text.txt`). Then by using a binary search it will compare the 2 files so see which words are spelled incorrectly in the text file.

My trouble lies with converting the text file all to lowercase so it can be compared to the dictionary which has been converted to lowercase.

The regular expression is in there because theres words in the text such as `long,` and the regex would take out the comma.

The error message i recieve is :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\S\Coursework\searchBinary.py", line 25, in <module>
    content = re.findall("[\w']+", content)
  File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

```
import re

def binS(lo,hi,target):

    if (lo>=hi):
        return False
    mid = (lo+hi) // 2
    piv = words[mid]
    if piv==target:
        return True
    if piv<target:
        return binS(mid+1,hi,target)
    return binS(lo,mid,target)



words = [s.strip("\n").lower() for s in open("words.txt")] 
words.sort() # sort the list

text = open("text.txt" , encoding="utf8")
content = text.read().split(" ")
content = [item.lower() for item in content]
content = re.findall("[\w']+", content)


for w in content:
    if not binS(0,len(words),w):
        print (w)
```

Comment: can you post stack trace of your error message?

Comment: please post your error!

Comment: @Mitiku edited with the error message

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi edited with the error message

Comment: It is saying that content is of the wrong type, and should be a string or bytes-like object. Basically, re.findall doesn't work on lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a string or bytes-like object but you are passing it a list.

If you run `print(type(content))` you’ll get

class 'list'

Try to recombine the text as a string before running the regex and it should work. Use `content = ' '.join(content)`

```
import re

def binS(lo,hi,target):

    if (lo>=hi):
        return False
    mid = (lo+hi) // 2
    piv = words[mid]
    if piv==target:
        return True
    if piv<target:
        return binS(mid+1,hi,target)
    return binS(lo,mid,target)

words = [s.strip("\n").lower() for s in open("dictionary.txt")] 
words.sort() # sort the list

text = open("temp.txt" , encoding="utf8")
content = text.read().split(" ")
content = [item.lower() for item in content]
content = ' '.join(content)
content = re.findall("[\w']+", content)


for w in content:
    if not binS(0,len(words),w):
        print (w)
```

I have a dictionary file named dictionary.txt and I put “Hello worl my nae is Bob” into temp.txt.

My output is:

> worl nae

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly due to the wrong type of object passed to the `re.findall` function, as already pointed out. I wanted to suggest a different approach you could try: avoid using the regular expressions altogether and replace the punctuation in the text with something like this...

```
for ch in '.,:;?!"·$%&/+*#@<=>-_\\`|^´~()[]{}':
    text = text.replace(ch, " ")
```

... and then get the list of words simply by doing:

```
words = text.split()
```